# Refresh pivot table on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a working VBA Macro in Excel for Windows, attached to a button, to recalculate and refresh all pivot tables.

I have shared this with a client who uses a Mac, and it does not work. I am unable to test which element is not working but suspect it is the pivot table refresh.

Is there anything here that would require translation from Windows to a Mac?

All source data for the pivot tables are linked to the 'Data' sheet.

```
'## Define current worksheet
Dim wkst As Worksheet
Set wkst = ActiveSheet

'## recalculate all formulas ##
Calculate 

'## select data sheet, find the whole range and name it PIVOT_RANGE ##     
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Name = "PIVOT_RANGE"

'## Refresh all pivot tables in the workbook ## 
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'## select original worksheet
wkst.Select
```

Comment: I don't know which code needs conversion, but you can simplify naming the data range to just the line `Range(Sheets("Data").Range("A1"),Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Name = "PIVOT_RANGE"`. This also removes most of the changing focus/selects in the code.

Comment: Thanks @Mistella that does simplify things considerably - and will also help narrow down whether it is indeed the Activeworkbook.RefreshAll statement that is causing the issue.